# Display a random post attachment on homepage in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, attachment

I'm trying to get 1 random image attached to a post, and display it on the front page (changing which image is displayed on refresh).  All the code I've seen is showing how to display an attachment from within the loop on the post page, but this will be getting the attachment from one page and displaying it on a different page.

Any help would be huge as I don't really have a starting point on this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to query attachments directly. They is actually a post type just for attachments. This bit of code will spit out the `<img>` tag for a random image:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array( 'post_status' => 'any', 'post_type' => 'attachment' ) ); 
$key = array_rand($query->posts, 1);

echo wp_get_attachment_image($query->posts[$key]->ID, 'medium');
```

The string `medium` can be replaced with another size you set in the media section of the dashboard, or a custom size you set in the code using [`add_image_size()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_image_size).

Comment: This worked, thanks! Just have to play around with sizing etc, but definitely gave me a good start.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but this should grab only one row from your database, and it makes full use of the WP_Query functions.

You can change the size of the image that is displayed by replacing `'full'` with an array (e.g. `array(200, 130)`). Check the [codex for `wp_get_attachment_image()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image) for more informaion.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby'           => 'rand',
    'post_type'         => 'attachment'
    'post_status'       => 'inherit',
    'posts_per_page'    => 1
)
$query = new WP_Query($args);

if($query->have_posts()) : while($query->have_posts() : $query->the_post();

        echo wp_get_attachment_image(get_the_ID(), 'full');

    endwhile;

    wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```